# String Manipulation in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a string in python and I'd like to take off the last three characters. How do I go about this?

So turn something like 'hello' to 'he'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a couple of ways to do it.

You could replace the whole string with a slice of itself.

```
s = "hello"
s = s[:-3] # string without last three characters
print s
# he
```

Alternatively you could explicitly strip the last three characters off the string and then assign that back to the string. Although arguably more readable, it's less efficient.

```
s = "hello"
s = s.rstrip(s[-3:])  # s[-3:] are the last three characters of string
                      # rstrip returns a copy of the string with them removed
print s
# he
```

In any case, you'll have to replace the original value of the string with a modified version because they are "immutable" (unchangeable) once set to a value.

Comment: Be careful with the last option:
`s = "helloxxxhelloxxx"
s = s.replace(s[-3:], '')

print s`

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> s = "hello"
>>> print(s[:-3])
he
```

For an explanation of how this works, see the question: [good primer for python slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/893).

Answer (score 4):

`"hello"[:-3]` - first `length - 3` characters.

`"hello"[:2]` - first 2 characters.

Answer (score 1):

type "hello"[:2]

or "hello"[:-3] which is the answer for removing the last three letters

hope this helps

Comment: This is not what was requested; what was requested was to remove the last three, not take the first two.

Comment: i just focused on the "he" from "hello" :) , its ok though

Answer (score 0):

`"hello"[:2]` is the easiest way to do this however the accurate answer for the problem 
would be as Saif al Harthi stated.  `"hello"[:-3]`

Answer (score -2):

if x is your string then you can use `x[:len(x)-3:+1]` to get the desired result

Comment: This works, but it is a very bad style, inefficient, redundant, and therefore bug-prone.